# What application can I use to create and order a photo book? (like Apple's iPhoto)

Tags: software-recommendation, printing, shotwell, photo

I have about 100 photo (each photo is about 9 MB) and I would like to make a photo book and then order it as a printed book.

Is there any native GUI app to do the job?

I have tried Shotwell but the only action I can do is sending the photos to a Picasa web album, and after that?

Web based solution like Blurb's Bookify does not work for me, the photo uploads is not working properly.

I am in Italy.

What do you suggest?

Is there anyone with a tested and working procedure to get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Shotwell](http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/).  Shotwell is shipped by default with Ubuntu.

[image]

If that doesn't cut it, take a look at [F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/).  F-Spot is a full-featured personal photo management application.

To download, install and more info, visit the website.  Or just click [**F-Spot** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/f-spot/)

There is also a list of optional [extensions](http://f-spot.org/Extensions) available.

Comment: May you please explain me how to use Shotwell in order to create a printed book?

Comment: Look under File-->Print.

Comment: In my version 0.12.3, File->Print is the standard print menu, there is no option to create an high quality photo book and order it to a printing facility.

Comment: Look at the addition in the answer.

Comment: Shotwell does not have a way to order printed photos.  However Shotwell can upload photos to Flickr, which has an option to send photos to Snapfish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Free Pixum Photo Book Software](http://www.pixum.co.uk/photo-book/software).